# Django как передать полученные данные в другой запрос

Tags: django, django-orm

Пример: получаю задачу по id

```
  {
        "id": 4,
        "userInfo": 1,
        "uuid": "5a722487",
        "title": "Comparing numbers"
  }
```

Получаю рекомендации к ней передаю в urls UserInfo и id-задачи чтобы исключить ее.
получаю случайные задачи

```
[
    {
        "id": 16,
        "userInfo": 1,
        "uuid": "1e6a7182",
        "title": "The opposite number"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "userInfo": 1,
        "uuid": "9de9f5d0",
        "title": "Your order, please"
    },
]
```

Можно ли из первого запроса сохранить id и userinfo чтобы не передавать их в urls для второго запроса

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь воспользоваться методом exclude(), чтобы исключить из выдачи объекты, соответствующие параметрам.
Например:

```
Tasks.objects.exclude(id=4)
```

Вернет QuerySet без объекта с id=4.